# Scala multiple constructors issue

Tags: scala, syntax, constructor

I can't understand why this code is wrong, the error message is:

```
error: '}' expected but '.' found.
```

on line

```
this.tX = cX
```

code:

```
class Quaternion {  
  private var tX: Float = 0
  private var tY: Float = 0
  private var tZ: Float = 0
  private var tW: Float = 1

  def this(cX: Float, cY: Float, cZ: Float, cW: Float) {
    this.tX = cX
    this.tY = cY
    this.tZ = cZ
    this.tW = cW
  }

  ...
```

Please help me fix my probably obvious mistake.

Comment: Constructor overloading in Scala works a lot different than in Java. There is plenty of resources about this. Just google it and you'll have more than enough.

Comment: I googled.  It took me here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should look at making this a case class, and immutable. That would look something like this (nb. generally I prefer doubles to floats):

```
case class Quaternion(tX: Double = 0.0, tY: Double = 0.0, tZ: Double = 0.0, tW: Double = 1.0)
```

Instances can then be created as per the following examples:

```
scala> val qDefault = Quaternion()
qDefault: Quaternion = Quaternion(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)

scala> val q1234 = Quaternion(1,2,3,4)
q1234: Quaternion = Quaternion(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0)

scala> val q0101 = Quaternion(tY = 1.0)
q0101: Quaternion = Quaternion(0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0)
```

Answer (score 10):

[Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf) like always answers it (§5.3.1 and example 5.3.3):

> To prevent inﬁnite cycles of constructor invocations, there is the
>   restriction that every self constructor invocation must refer to a
>   constructor deﬁnition which precedes it (i.e. it must refer to either
>   a preceding auxiliary constructor or the primary constructor of the
>   class).

Which in your case change it to:

```
def this(cX: Float, cY: Float, cZ: Float, cW: Float) {
      this()
      this.tX = cX
      this.tY = cY
      this.tZ = cZ
      this.tW = cW
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I would strongly recommend to use immutable case class with companion object, constructor overload or default values:

```
case class Quaternion(cX: Float, cY: Float, cZ: Float, cW: Float)

object Quaternion {
   def apply() = new Quaternion(0,0,0,1)
}

scala> Quaternion()
res0: Quaternion = Quaternion(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)
```

or

```
case class Quaternion(cX: Float, cY: Float, cZ: Float, cW: Float) {
   def this() = this(0,0,0,1)
}

scala> new Quaternion()
res2: Quaternion = Quaternion(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)
```

or

```
case class Quaternion(cX: Float = 0, cY: Float = 0, cZ: Float = 0, cW: Float = 1)

scala> Quaternion()
res0: Quaternion = Quaternion(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)
```

If you need to change var, you can always use copy method.

Comment: Voted because I think companion object technique is more general than chosen answer. Somehow related, I was looking for this in order to create a case class for a Json Writes. It was useful, but I couldn't use Json.writes because of a known limitation related to apply and Json: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2031 . This could be workarounded by not overloading apply: https://gist.github.com/stephanos/4717443